# Accessing keys from dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary of dictionaries such as

```
ab={'apple':7,'ball':9,'src':{'dst':6},'svr':{'pre':{'ere':0}}}
```

And i want extract all the keys in this format.

```
keys=['apple','ball',['src','dst'],['svr','pre','ere']]
```

I had been trying to do in this way,

```
for k in ab:
    if  not isinstance(ab[k],dict):
        new_dict_keys.append(k)
    else:
        new_dict_keys.append(k)
        new_dict_keys.append(ab[k])
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Your ab dict still looks wrong. What about the '7'?

Comment: @Sayse That dictionary will go just fine if he adds an apostrophe to the p that is missing it next to dst. Or what do you guys see as the problem?

Comment: @chromaerror - The question has been edited since.

Comment: Oh, now that you say it I see it! Apologies

Comment: why are `['svr','pre','ere']` all in the same level?

Answer (score 1):

One solution using recursion:

```
def get_keys(d:dict):
    out = []
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            lst = get_keys(value)
            out.append([key]+lst[0] if isinstance(lst[0], list) else [key] + lst)
        else:
            out.append(key)
    return out

d = {'apple':7,'ball':9,'src':{'dst':6},'svr':{'pre':{'ere':0}}}
print(get_keys(d))
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'ball', ['src', 'dst'], ['svr', 'pre', 'ere']]
```